# Dynamically update row style javaFX

Tags: javafx

Suppose you have an ObservableList of Product

```
ObservableList<Product> = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Where Product is defined as:

```
public class Product{

SimpleStringProperty name;
SimpleStringProperty status;

public void setName(String name){
    this.name.set(name);
}

public String getName(){
     return this.name.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty(){
    return name;
}

public void setStatus(String status){
    this.status.set(status);
}

public String getStatus(){
     return this.status.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty statusProperty(){
    return status;
}}
```

In order to have the rows of my TableView bold if status is "Available" i've written this rowFactory:

```
mytable.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<Product>, TableRow<Product>>() {

        @Override
        public TableRow<Product> call(TableView<Product> param) {
            return new TableRow<Product>() {

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Product item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item == null) {
                        setStyle("");
                    } else {
                        String status= item.getStatus();
                        if (!status.equals("Available")) {
                            setStyle("");

                        } else {
                            setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");

                        }
                    }

                }
            };
        }

    });
```

The problem is that if i update the model( observablelist) by changing some product' status to available when the table is already displayed, the row doesn't change its style! Can you help me?

Comment: Use a listener.

Comment: Ok, so i add a listener to the status property?